# How to create dynamic form in sails.js with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sails.js

I am using sails.js 1.0 with vue.js and want to create a dynamic form that contains a dynamic amount of inputs based on the user's preference. So the user should be able to add another input, type in the data and send the complete form with the dynamic amount of data.

My form looks like this:

```
<ajax-form action="addStuff" :syncing.sync="syncing" :cloud-error.sync="cloudError" @submitted="submittedForm()" :handle-parsing="handleParsingForm">
...
    <input class="form-control" id="input1" name="input1" type="text" :class="[formErrors.password ? 'is-invalid' : '']"
                      v-model.trim="formData.input1" placeholder="Input #1" autofocus>
...
    <ajax-button type="submit" :syncing="syncing" class="btn btn-dark">Save changes</ajax-button>

</ajax-form>
```

The action `addStuff` in sails looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  friendlyName: 'Do some stuff',
  description: 'Do some stuff with the form data.',

  inputs: {

    input1: {
      description: 'The first input.',
      required: true
    }

  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    // Do some stuff with the inputs
    return exits.success();

  }
};
```

I know that normally I would be able to create a dynamic form using vue.js by

- setting the data of the Vue instance to an array
- creating a two-way-binding
- implementing a `v-for` loop in the form, that then creates an input for every element in the data object
- modifying this array by inserting a new element in the array every time the user wants to add another input.

But with sails and this `ajax-form`, I do not know how to access the vue instance and the data element of it and how to make this also dynamic in the action. Obviously the input would need to contain an array.

How would it be possible to achieve such a dynamic form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the missing part. Sails.js is using [parasails](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parasails) which is built on top of vue.js.

When generating a new sails page using the sails generator `sails new test-project`, there is also a contact form generated which also contains the necessary code which can be adapted for this purpose.

That contact form basically consists of

- The .ejs page (=the html code that renders the form) in views/pages
- The `contact.page.js` client-side script in assets/js/pages
- The server side controller `deliver-contact-form-message.js` in api/controllers

In the client-side script, the initial `formData` can be set:

```
parasails.registerPage('maindivid', {
  //  ╦╔╗╔╦╔╦╗╦╔═╗╦    ╔═╗╔╦╗╔═╗╔╦╗╔═╗
  //  ║║║║║ ║ ║╠═╣║    ╚═╗ ║ ╠═╣ ║ ║╣
  //  ╩╝╚╝╩ ╩ ╩╩ ╩╩═╝  ╚═╝ ╩ ╩ ╩ ╩ ╚═╝
  data: {

    // Main syncing/loading state for this page.
    syncing: false,

    // Form data
    formData: { /* … */ },

    // For tracking client-side validation errors in our form.
    // > Has property set to `true` for each invalid property in `formData`.
    formErrors: { /* … */ },

    // Server error state for the form
    cloudError: '',

    // Success state when form has been submitted
    cloudSuccess: false,

  },
  ...
```

as well as methods etc.

It follows a similar structure than plain vue.js.

To achieve what I was trying to do I added a field as array to the `formData`

```
 formData: {
  myinputs: [
    {
      key: '',
      value: ''
    }
  ]
},
```

Then I bound that in the .ejs file:

```
<div class="form-row" v-for="(filter, index) in formData.mypinputs">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" :class="[formErrors.password ? 'is-invalid' : '']"
                          v-model.trim="formData.myinputs[index].key" placeholder="My field">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" @click="addFilterForm">add field</button>
</div>
```

And finally added a method to the client-side script in `contact.page.js` (or your name) that gets called when the user clicks the "add field" button.

```
  methods: {

    addFilterForm: function() {
      this.formData.myinputs.push({
        key: '',
        value: ''
      });
    },
```

Because of the two way binding, as soon as an element is added to the array `formData.myinputs`, another input is created and added to the DOM.

Comment: I am learning Parasails. Can you explain to me the difference between parasails and vue js? I am a bit confused. e.g. in Parasails, data is an object, while in vue data is a function.

Comment: @adis I do not really understand your issue, please file a separate question with more information. In the above example, formData is what data would be in vue.js (both are objects).